# Error C2582 Boost ODEINT when using iterator-based integration

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, odeint

For a project I am working on I need to use an iterator-based solution in order to stop the integration when certain conditions are met. 
It looks like the following code, when applied to our specific situation, will work.  When using Visual Studio 2010 and 2013 and Boost 1.57, the following code works and compiles.

```
 {
      auto stepper = make_controlled( 1.0e-6 , 1.0e-6 , runge_kutta_cash_karp54< state_type > () );
      state_type x = {{ 10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 }};
      auto iter = boost::find_if( make_adaptive_time_range( stepper , lorenz() , x , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.01 ) ,
                                             []( const std::pair< const state_type & , double > &x ) 
                                             {return ( x.first[0] < 0.0 ); }
                                             );

      cout << iter->second << "\t" << iter->first[0] << "\t" << iter->first[1] << "\t" << iter->first[2] << "\n";
 }
```

The problem arises because we are also interested in using the Bulirsch-Stoer method.  When I try to implement the Bulirsch-Stoer stepper as follows:

```
{
    bulirsch_stoer<state_type> stepper(1e-9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);        
    state_type x = {{ 10.0 , 10.0 , 10.0 }};

    auto iter = boost::find_if( make_adaptive_time_range( stepper , lorenz() , x , 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.01 ) ,
                                 []( const std::pair< const state_type & , double > &x ) {
                                    return ( x.first[0] < 0.0 ); } );

            cout << iter->second << "\t" << iter->first[0] << "\t" << iter->first[1] << "\t" << iter->first[2] << "\n";
}
```

I get the following compilation error.

```
 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(275): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'boost::numeric::odeint::adaptive_time_iterator<Stepper,System,State,StepperTag>'
 1>          with
 1>          [
 1>              Stepper=boost::numeric::odeint::bulirsch_stoer<state_type>,
 1>              System=lorenz,
 1>              State=state_type,
 1>              StepperTag=boost::numeric::odeint::controlled_stepper_tag
 1>          ]
 Etc.
```

The error must be related to Visual Studio because the exact same code compiles when I use gcc.  Can anyone help me to get the Bulirsch-Stoer stepper to work in make_adaptive_time_range?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could try pulling the latest version of odeint from github. Some problems with msvc have been addressed since boost 1.57, so you might be lucky and your problem goes away...

Comment: The latest odeint version from github didn't resolve the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, I've opened an issue on the odeint github page and we will try to look into this: https://github.com/headmyshoulder/odeint-v2/issues/149